# Array merge in ASP classic

Tags: arrays, function, asp-classic, merge

I'm working on an array_merge function for ASP classic.  What I have seems to be working, until one (or both) params are empty or not arrays.  Here's what I have so far:

```vb
function array_merge(left, right)
  dim total_size
  dim i
  dim merged
  ' Convert "left" to an array
  if not isArray(left) then
    left = Array(left)
  end if
  ' Convert "right" to an array
  if not isArray(right) then
    right = Array(right)
  end if
  ' Start with "left" and add the elements of "right"
  right_size = ubound(right)
  total_size = ubound(left) + right_size + 1
  merged = left
  redim preserve merged(total_size)
  for i = 0 to ubound(right)
    merged(right_size + i + 1) = right(i)
  next
  ' Return value
  array_merge = merged
end function
```

I get the error:

```
Error Type:
Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01B6)
Object doesn't support this property or method: 'merged'
/_inc/nav/left-nav.inc, line 21
```

From the line `merged(right_size + i + 1) = right(i)`.  Any wisdom on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What was the input when you got that error?

Comment: Just throwing this out there -- `LEFT` and `RIGHT` are functions in VBScript.  Is it possible that the code is actually barfing on `right(i)`?   You might want to change the function's parameter names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LittleBobbyTables is right, you should change the parameters.

I think depending on you inputs an extra check for object could solve your issue

```
function array_merge(left, right)
  dim right_size
  dim total_size
  dim i
  dim merged
  ''// Convert "left" to an array
  if not isArray(left) then
    left = Array(left)
  end if
  ''// Convert "right" to an array
  if not isArray(right) then
    right = Array(right)
  end if
  ''// Start with "left" and add the elements of "right"

  right_size = ubound(right)
  total_size = ubound(left) + right_size + 1

  merged = array()
  redim merged(total_size)
  dim counter : counter = 0

  for i = lbound(left) to ubound(left)
    if isobject(left(i))then
        set merged(counter) = left(i)
    else
        merged(counter) = left(i)
    end if
    counter=counter+1
  next

  for i = lbound(right) to ubound(right)
    if isobject(right(i))then
        set merged(counter) = right(i)
    else
        merged(counter) = right(i)
     end if
  next


  ''// Return value
  array_merge = merged
end function
```

Some Testcode:

```
dim a: a=100
dim b: b=200

dim c: set c=nothing
dim d: set d=nothing

dim e: set e=server.createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
dim f: set f=server.createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")


dim x,y,z,zz

x = array_merge(a,b)
y = array_merge(c,d)
z = array_merge(e,f)
zz = array_merge(a,e)

response.write x(0)
response.write x(1)

''// Accessing Nothing Values throw Error
''//response.write y(0)
''//response.write y(1)

response.write z(0).GetExtensionName("test.doc")
response.write z(1).GetExtensionName("test.doc")

response.write zz(0)
response.write zz(1).GetExtensionName("test.doc")
```

Comment: Instead of iterating through left, why not `redim preserve left( total_size )` and then add right's values to it?

Answer (score 1):

Small efficiency improvement to Paolo Pta's answer. There's no need to iterate through arr1; just "redim preserve" it.

```
Function array_merge( arr1, arr2 )
    dim arr1_size, arr2_size, total_size, i, counter
    if not isArray( arr1 ) then arr1 = Array( arr1 )
    if not isArray( arr2 ) then arr2 = Array( arr2 )

    arr1_size = ubound( arr1 ) : arr2_size = ubound( arr2 )
    total_size = arr1_size + arr2_size + 1
    counter = arr1_size + 1
    Redim Preserve arr1( total_size )
    For i = lbound( arr2 ) to arr2_size
        If isobject( arr2( i ) )then
            set arr1( counter ) = arr2( i )
        Else
            arr1( counter ) = arr2( i )
        End if
        counter = counter + 1
    Next
    array_merge = arr1
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

A few years later, but maybe someone can use it.

```
function array_merge(arr, arr2)
    for each elm in arr2
        redim preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
        arr(UBound(arr)) = elm
    next

    array_merge = arr
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but there is something that you need to fix, so that you can obtain all the values from the two arrays.

You need to upgrade the counter inside the second FOR, like you did on the first one.
Otherwise one of the values from the second array wont be assigned.

Take this code as an example:

```
''//Build the Arrays

 Dim a,b,c
 a=array("a1","a2") : b=array("b1","b2") : c=array_merge(a,b)

''//Run the code

 For Each i In c 
    Response.Write i &"<br />"
    Next

''//The main function

 Function array_merge(arr1, arr2)
    ''//Declare all function variables
     dim arr1_size,arr2_size,total_size,i,merged,counter

    ''//Fix empty or none arrays
     if not isArray(arr1) then arr1 = Array(arr1) end if
     if not isArray(arr2) then arr2 = Array(arr2) end if

    ''// Get and set the Arrays Size
    arr1_size = ubound(arr1) : arr2_size = ubound(arr2)
    total_size = arr1_size + arr2_size    + 1

    ''//Create a temporary array and assign it a size
    merged = array()
    redim merged(total_size)
    counter = 0

    ''//Create one single Array with the two others by looping them
    For i = lbound(arr1) to ubound(arr1)
      IF isobject(arr1(i)) then
        set merged(counter) = arr1(i)
        Else
        merged(counter) = arr1(i)
        End if
      counter=counter+1
      Next
    For i = lbound(arr2) to ubound(arr2)
     If isobject(arr2(i))then
       set merged(counter) = arr2(i)
       Else
       merged(counter) = arr2(i)
       End if
       counter=counter+1
       Next

    ''// Return the value
    array_merge = merged
    End Function
```

Comment: I'm confused is this a question or an answer?

Comment: Isn't it clear that this is a proposed replacement for the OP's code, which solves the problem?   It declares a function called array_merge, and the answer says "you need to do such and such to achieve such and such".   I haven't reviewed the code in detail, but I'm not clear why it's even getting flagged?   Maybe if we replace "we" with "you" it would be clearer that this is an answer?

Comment: @GreenAsJade Thanks for noticing that this is an answer and editing it so it's clearer. Sorry about the mistake when reviewing flagged posts.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Hows the stack snippet relevant?, we are talking about "server-side" scripting languages.

Comment: I wondered about the snippet too - but I just realised now that the poster thought they needed to put the code in a snippet for formatting - a bunch of ASP code just wrapped in snippet tags instead of {} code.

Comment: This is THE answer.  The other one doesn't work properly